# Cancel C-b in tmux

Tags: tmux

In emacs C-g cancels any command that has begun. Is there a similar solution in tmux for after you have pressed Ctrl-b? I thought about researching this by hitting lots of keys but that would only make this worse.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use any key that is not bound to anything. From what I see in the man page `Ctrl-g` is in fact *not* bound to anything (in regular mode) so you can use it after `Ctrl-b`.

If you want to explicitly bind this `noop` functionality to `Ctrl-g` key, you can do it by placing something like this in `tmux.conf`:

```
bind C-g run 'true'
```